# I need to make a circular progress bar with rounded ends

Tags: javascript, html, css

I need to create a circular progress bar. The highlighted segment has an outline and the end points are rounded, like this:

[image]

I did this one, but I can't create the rounded edges of progress segment line.

```css
.pie {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: .5em;
  width: 8em;
  height: 8em;
  position: relative;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.pie:after {
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: block;
  content: "";
  background: #fff;
  position: absolute;
    left: .5em;
  top: .5em;
  height: 7em;
  width: 7em;
}



.p1 {
  background-image: linear-gradient(-30deg, #ddd 50%, transparent 50%),
                    linear-gradient(90deg, #ddd 50%, steelblue 50%);
}
```

```html
<div class="pie p1"></div>
```

Comment: Has you tried to create a pair of tiny circles at the segment ends?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Easy way use **svg** with **circle**. The **circle** has property `stroke-linecap: round` exactly what you need. And you can control the progress bar with property `stroke-dashoffset`.

```css
*,
::after,
::before {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, 'Segoe UI', Roboto, Oxygen, Ubuntu, Cantarell,
    'Open Sans', 'Helvetica Neue', sans-serif;
}

body {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  display: grid;
  place-items: center;
  color: hsl(231, 9%, 16%);
  background-color: hsl(240, 20%, 98%);
  position: relative;
}

section {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column;
  align-items: center;
  gap: .5rem;
}

h3,
span {
  line-height: 1;
}

section span {
  font-size: 2em;
  font-weight: 500;
}

div {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  position: relative;
}

h3 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  font-size: 2.5em;
}

svg {
  height: 150px;
  width: 150px;
  transform: rotate(0deg);
}
#progress,
#progress-border,
#track,
#border-track {
  fill: transparent;
}
#progress {
  stroke: hsl(161, 100%, 43%);
  stroke-width: 14px;
  stroke-linecap: round;
  stroke-dasharray: 440;
  stroke-dashoffset: 140; /* Change number value to shift progress bar */
}
#progress-border {
  stroke: hsl(161, 100%, 37%);
  stroke-width: 10px;
  stroke-linecap: round;
  stroke-dasharray: 440;
  stroke-dashoffset: 140; /* Change number value to shift progress bar */
}
#track {
  stroke: hsl(0, 0%, 100%);
  stroke-width: 10px;
}
#border-track {
  stroke: hsl(0, 0%, 93%);
  stroke-width: 12px;
}
```

```html
<section>
  <div>
    <h3>Text</h3>
    <svg>
       <circle id="border-track" cx="75" cy="75" r="65"></circle>
       <circle id="track" cx="75" cy="75" r="65"></circle>
       <circle id="progress" cx="75" cy="75" r="65"></circle>
       <circle id="progress-border" cx="75" cy="75" r="65"></circle>
     </svg>
  </div>
  <span>70%</span>
</section>
```

Comment: How did you arrive at `stroke-dasharray: 440;`?

Comment: @Parzival Experimentally. First add **stroke-dasharray** property with **0** in CSS, then open devtools (Chrome, Firefox) and changing the value of **stroke-dasharray** inside the devtools to get needed result.

Comment: Thanks! Actually I figured that here `stroke-dasharray` is essentially the circumference, or `2πr`. In this case since r = 65, the optimal value should be 2π * 65 = 408.4, so 409 is technically a more optimal value